# How to resolve dynamic property name using Spring SPEL?

Tags: spring, spring-el

I've an instance variable the value of which should be set by looking up a dynamic property name.

```
Class Test {
    @Value("#{T(java.lang.String).format('filter.%s.disable', getClass().getSimpleName())}")
    private boolean disable;
}
```

`disable` should evaluate to `true` when `filter.Test.disable = true` and `false` otherwise. I also want to set a default value `false` if the property is not defined, which is usually done using the following syntax, but I'm not sure in this case.
`@Value("${property:default}")`

I'm getting the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value
>   [filter.BeanExpressionContext.disable]

Also tried `@Value("${'dcs.cloud.filter.'#{getClass().getSimpleName()}'.disable'}")` and some other combinations of `#` and `$` to no avail.

The [SPEL doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) shows useless `parser.parseExpression` calls to evaluate expressions, which uses a different syntax, and no one does in reality. Looks like they picked out code from the unit tests instead of real examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the class in which the expression is declared that way. `getClass()` there acts on the root object for the expression evaluation (the `BeanExpressionContext` in this case).

It's not clear why you can't just use `filter.Test.disable` here (unless, perhaps you are trying to get the actual class when `Test` is subclassed).

You can't do that.

It might be easier to implement `EnvironmentAware` and set the boolean by getting the property from the environment.

Comment: I did just that, injected `Environment` and looked up the value. I didn't want to hard-code the class name because a) refactoring would break it b) won't work for subclasses.